# My POST route to update my user profile is not working in js web app. (Mongoose, Node and Passport)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

Hi I am currently stuck where my update route is broken and when I click the update button, the user profile does not get updated in the database. I am using passport to get the user id but it's greyed out at the top of the file where I am requiring it and I don't know why.

I have done this before in a similar project and it worked fine, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Thanks in advance.

```
user.js: 

const router = require('express').Router();
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/edit-profile', async (req, res, next) => {
  const update = {firstname: req.body.firstname, lastname: req.body.lastname, email: req.body.email, benchpress: req.body.benchpress, squat: req.body.squat, deadlift: req.body.deadlift}
  const _id = ObjectID(req.session.passport.user);
  const filter = { id: _id };
  const updatedDocument = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true });

  //return res.status(200).send(updatedDocument);
  res.render('profile', updatedDocument);
});
```

edit-profile.ejs:

```
<div class="main">
    <form action="/edit-profile" method="POST" class="ep-form">
        <div>
            <label for="name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text"name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<%= user.firstname %>" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text"name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<%= user.lastname %>" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email"name="email" id="email" value="<%= user.email %>" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Bench Press:</label>
            <input type="text"name="benchpress" id="benchpress" value="<%= user.benchpress %>" placeholder="Bench Press">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Squat:</label>
            <input type="text"name="squat" id="squat" value="<%= user.squat %>" placeholder="Squat">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Deadlift:</label>
            <input type="text"name="deadlift" id="deadlift" value="<%= user.deadlift %>" placeholder="Dead Lift">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
    <a href="./profile">Back to profile</a>
</div>
```

passport initialise:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        // Username/email does NOT exist
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Username/email not registered',
          });
        }
        // Email exist and now we need to verify the password
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        return isMatch
          ? done(null, user)
          : done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: <button type="submit">Update</button>

Comment: I just changed that but still doesn't work. I don't know why passport package is greyed out at top, it says its not being used

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, "is not working" can mean anything from "not being called" to "not doing the expected thing" to "it's crashing". Also, the `passport` const isn't being used in the code you're showing.

Comment: Sorry by its not working I mean when I click the update button, the user profile does not get updated in the database. In regards to the passport const, I thought when I get the set the _id variable it should be using passport in order to get the id of the user currently logged in?

Comment: You need to initialize passport somewhere and also setup express to use sessions, but that part is missing from your code snippets. Importing passport on its own doesn't really do much.

Comment: I just added the file where I setup passport, does this help with figuring out where the  problem is?